"Property HostedZoneId cannot be empty" even though I import it
Even though, I import HostedZoneId but I still meet the error.
This is my template
Parameters:
  HostedZoneId:
    Type: String

CloudFrontDNSRecord:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: !Ref HostedZoneId 
      Type: A

I already to install ACM to route 53 and it was issued by AWS
Then I try to implement by hard-string (my hosted zone id). It's not working
I refer to this document, still not find the answer
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-route53-recordset.html
Please help me.

You need to add both hosted zones in template

CloudFrontDNSRecord:
    Type: 'AWS::Route53::RecordSet'
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: !Ref HostedZoneId
      Type: A
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: !GetAtt myCloudFrontDistribution.DomainName
        HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2  # Fixed CloudFront Hosted Zone ID

and Always try to add hardcoded values, test it, if it works update it with dynamic variables and attributes, that will help you to debug much faster.
